# Find the minimum value of a list and print the corresponding index from another list

Tags: python, list, selection

Say I have some lists, e.g.

```
list1 = [9.2,6.6,3.1,6.9]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to find the minimum value of `list1` and take that minimum value's index and use it to print out the value from `list2` for that corresponding index.

The `min(list1)` would give me `3.1`, with an index of `2`, now i want to `print list2[2]`.

Should note that these are not my actual values, they are much more complicated. I just need the general idea.

Comment: What if there are more than one 3s?

Comment: Maybe I should have said that no values can be the same, it is always changing and never the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list1, list2 = [9.2,6.6,3.1,6.9], [1,2,3,4]
print list2[min((j,i) for i, j in enumerate(list1))[1]]
# 3
```

**Explanation:**

`min((j,i) for i, j in enumerate(list1))` will give the smallest element along with its index. In this case, it will return `(3.1, 2)`. So we take only the second element and get the element corresponding to it from `list2`.

The other way to do the same would be

```
print min(zip(list1, list2))[1]
# 3
```

Comment: It works, thanks. is enumerate just a term or is it an actual function?

Comment: @BobUnger Its a builtin function :)

Comment: zip function is even better since i've seen and used it before. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

this should do

```
print (list2[list1.index(min(list1))])
```

in long form:

```
list1 = [9.2,6.6,3.1,6.9]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]
a = min(list1)
b= list1.index(a)  
print (list2[b])
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be done using index:

```
list2[list1.index(min(list1))]
```

Output:

```
3
```